# multiple newlines not being respected in Slack using microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

When I send text with multiple paragraphs to the user there are never blank lines between paragraphs in slack.  Using the emulator or the web client it has the blank lines but not slack.  Here is sample code using the javascript SDK:

```
const replyText = "Paragraph1\n\nParagraph2\n\nParagraph3";
await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text(replyText));
```

In slack it shows as:

```
Paragraph1
Paragraph2
Paragraph3
```

How do I get slack to show the blank newlines?

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of trial and error and research I stumbled on a solution.  Slack requires those newlines to be changed to `<br/>` tags.  Unfortunately, the emulator will just show them as `<br/>` in text (haven't tested with other channels).  As a result, you need to selectively do it for slack:

```
var replyText = "Paragraph1\n\nParagraph2\n\nParagraph3";

if (context.activity.channelId === 'slack') {
   // slack doesn't respect regular newlines so need to convert to <br/>
   replyText = replyText.replace(/\n\n/g, "<br/><br/>");
}

await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text(replyText));
```